# Does the Chain Rule in Leibniz notation cancel terms?

Tags: calculus, notation, math-history

I understand this notation is now a differential operator and this is the limit of a quotient, but Leibniz regarded $\frac {dy}{dx}$ as a quotient.  In Leibniz's theory where $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is a quotient, do the terms in chain rule cancel out?

For instance below, there are two instances of $du$.
$$
y = f(u), u = u_1 = u_2 = g(x)
$$
$$ 
\frac {dy}{du_2} \Big|_{g(x)} \cdot \frac {du_1}{dx} \Big|_{x}  
= (f \circ g)'(x) = (f' \circ g)(x) \cdot g'(x)
$$

It's my understanding that:
$$(du_1 = g(x+h) - g(x)) \ne (du_2 = (g(x) +h) - g(x))$$
becomes the following under the infinitesimal theory Leibniz used:
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {(du_1 = g(x+h) - g(x)) = (du_2 = (g(x) +h) - g(x))}$$
$$du_1 =du_2$$

and the above terms $du_1, du_2$ cancel out, leaving $\frac {dy}{dx}$.

If these terms do not cancel and are unequal, why is $du_1 = du_2 = du$ used in  the definition of the chain rule in modern theory?  Are there advantages to viewing things like this from infinitesimal theory like Leibniz?

Comment: what are u_1 and u_2?

Comment: How many times did you already ask a question regarding Leibniz notation :)?

Comment: This is a different question

Comment: @Buraian added them in

Comment: For differentiable functions, an **infinitesimal** change of $h$ gives that $g(x+h)$ is in fact infinitesimally close to $g(x)$, and hence is “equal” to $g(x)+h$. So if you are playing with actual infinitesimals, which is what Leibniz was doing, then you *do* have equality. It only fails to become an equality when you no longer work with infinitesimals, at which point the notation [no longer represents an actual ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio) and so there is no talk of “cancellation” anyway.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so there is no equality using current theory due to $\frac {dy}{dx}$ being the limit of a quotient, but with Leibniz's theory of infinitesimals $\frac {dy}{dx}$ was a quotient, the equality above $du_1 = du_2$ holds and therefore $du$ cancels out.  It's my understanding things can be setup like Leibniz's theory with *non-standard analysis*. I was curious about that for awhile!

Comment: @Nick: One has to be careful: it is not immediate the $g(x+h) = g(x)+h$ holds when $h$ is an infinitesimal: you have to actually *prove it* (it’s essentially the fact that $g$ is continuous because it is differentiable). Only after you prove it do you get to “cancel” them in non-standard analysis.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin do you know if viewing the theory as Leibniz did provides any helpful insight into other items, similar to the chain rule cancelling out?  I have found little resource on this.

Comment: @Nick: “Vieweing the theory as Leibniz did” leads to logical contradictions. It takes some care to clean it up properly. The “resources” are non-standard analysis. Leibniz notation is useful because it is intuitive, but you still have *prove* the things it “suggests”. I already mentioned, in that other post, some examples, like the formula for the derivative of the inverse. You don’t get a free lunch out of Leibniz notation: you just push the issues to a different place.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin per above, if considered in the theory of infinitesimals is $\frac {dy} {dx} = \frac {f(g(x+h) - g(x))}{g(x+h) - g(x)}$?

Comment: @Nick. Of course not. Why would you get that? You get $\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{(x+h)-h}$, If $g(x+h)=g(x)+h$ (using continuity), then you can rewrite as $\frac{f(g(x)+h)-f(g(x))}{h} = \frac{f(g(x)+h)-g(x)}{g(x)+h-g(x)}\cdot\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin did you mean : $\frac {f(g(x)+h) - f(g(x))}{g(x)+h-g(x)} \cdot \frac{g(x+h) -g(x)}{h} = \frac {f(g(x) +h) - f(g(x))}{h}$?  I think the numerator of first term after the equality in your comment is incorrect

Comment: @Nick: Yes, there is an $f$ missing in the subtrahend of that numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equality using the widely used theory of [limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) because $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is the limit of a quotient, however with Leibniz's theory of infinitesimals $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is a quotient.  Leibniz's infinitesimal theory has logical contradictions and to resolve them the theory of [non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) on the [hyperreal numebers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) can be used.  The hyperreals $\mathbb{R}*$ are an extension to the reals with infinitesimals $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^*$. The derivative and integral of calculus are expressed with the [standard part function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function) which is $s : \mathbb{R}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

With non-standard analysis the above equality $du_1 = du_2 = g(x+h) = g(x) + h$ holds if it is proven.  For instance $g(x)$ is continuous because it is differentiable.  When proven $du$ cancels out.  When terms are cancelled out due to equality the following is the result:

$$y = f(x), u = g(x)$$
$$
\frac {dy}{du} \frac {du}{dx} = \frac {f(g(x+h)) - f(g(x)))}{g(x+h)-g(x)} \frac {g(x+h) -g(x)}{h} = \frac {f(g(x+h) -g(x))}{h}
$$

due to continuity, $g(x) + h - g(x) = g(x+h) - g(x)$ then the result is:
$$
\frac {f(g(x) + h) - f(g(x))} {h}
$$

This appears to agree with the result using limits:
$$
f'(g(x)) = \lim_{h\rightarrow \infty}{\frac {f(g(x) + h) - f(g(x))} {h}}
$$