# Non-Standard Analysis: applying the chain rule using differential notation?

Tags: calculus, math-history, nonstandard-analysis

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042414/does-the-chain-rule-in-leibniz-notation-cancel-terms/4087928#4087928) about applying the chain rule to the original theory of Infinitesimal Calculus (as Leibniz originally defined it).  I provided an answer based on feedback.  Does anyone know if this answer is correct?  If not, does anyone have an example of applying the chain rule using non-standard analysis?

I'm interested how Calculus was used in Leibniz's era and how close the results are to the modern limit theory.  For example, using his differential notation appears useful for cancelling out long chains, making calculations easier.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. Regardless of whether you back it up by standard analysis, nonstandard analysis, or no rigor at all, the chain rule is useful for cancelling out long chains in Leibniz notation. Are you just asking "what is the statement and proof of the chain rule in Robinson's nonstandard analysis?"

Comment: I'm most interested in how the rule would have been applied in Leibniz original theory